# LR 3: Preset adds dark vignette, but how?

Tags: lightroom, presets, vignetting

In Lightroom 3, I have some presets (example: [whoiswolf_herbst_licht](http://www.presetsheaven.com/2010/12/08/28-free-lightroom-presets-from-chris/)) that seem to darken the edges of the photo. However, I can't figure out how they do this. There is nothing that shows up in the Effects panel (Post-Crop Vignetting) or in the Lens Correction panel.

So, how else can one darken the edges of a photo in LR?

Comment: Is "example: whoiswolf_herbst_licht" supposed to be a link?

Comment: No, it's the name of the Lightroom preset he's using.

Comment: Download link for that preset is at the foot of [this article](http://www.presetsheaven.com/2010/12/08/28-free-lightroom-presets-from-chris/). It's in the [Free Downloads](http://www.presetsheaven.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=109) package.

Answer (score 7):

If you open the plugin file in a text editor, you can see all the settings associated with the preset. In the case of this one, I can find the following:

```
VignetteAmount = -100,
VignetteMidpoint = 0,
```

Which suggests that it's not using 'post-crop vignette' but the lens correction vignette instead. You could verify this by applying the preset, and checking the value under 'Lens correction > Manual > Lens Vignetting'.

In my opinion this is a poor choice, as applying the effect to a cropped image would only apply vignetting to the uncropped version, so e.g. if you cropped the bottom right off the image, the top left would be darker than the other corners, making it look odd.

Comment: I believe in early versions of LR they did not have the option for post crop vignette, so this preset could easily have originated before the option was even present. Either that, or they just made a poor choice when creating it.

Comment: I think it behaved like post-crop vignette, but was just called 'vignette', IIRC. If Adobe kept the same tag for the different behaviour of lens-correction vignette, then that's pretty bad!